# Adding a calendar to my website

Tags: php, calendar, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I am making a website from scratch that will let users create accounts. I plan on having 4 type of accounts(Customer,Employee/Owner,Rep/Salesman,and Dealer). Out of those 4 type of accounts, the owner and the rep are the only ones who will see a calendar once they log-in. The owner should be able to modify events from the rep's calendar, and the rep can obviously modify his/her own calendar as well. I am not planning on making a calendar from scratch, but rather to get one that meet my needs from my website. I honestly don't know where to start looking, or what are some good scripts to get what I want done, so any help and thoughts are appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seems like quite a large task.

But have a look at this website with [this calendar script](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/calendar-function/) in PHP, it might be a good place to start. If you want to hand code it.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but that's very basic piece of code. Do you know of any framework that I could implement into my website that has a calendar plug-in built in already?

Comment: @MiguelLeonDuque No idea of something pre-made but I'm sure there is must be something if you search. Basic if you're not a beginner haha :)