# Reading a CSV file from a JSP

Tags: java, javascript, mysql, jsp, csv

I wrote a small log-in java program that works with servlets, and JSPs using the MVC pattern that allows me to register and log-in accounts(if we can call them that) to my local mySQL DataBase. I am using sessions to pass values between the servlet and the JSP, and I have a list of if statements on the servlet that work as validation for invalid inputs. Right now when my application is executed this happens:

- Sign_Up.jsp opens up and displays UserName and Password fields with a submit button below it. Also it shows a link on the top left corner to the Log_In.jsp. If you enter an username and password that follows requirements, an account is created on the database, and you are redirected to the Welcome.JSP which only shows a few lines of text. (I am not checking weather the password and username entered are unique atm, so there are duplication entries in the user table on the DB)
- If you click on the link at the top of the Sign_UP.jsp, then you are redirected to the Log_In.jsp. Here you are required to enter your credentials, if they exist on the database you are redirected to the Welcome.jsp , otherwise you are told that they are invalid and that you need to enter them again.

-----------------------------------THIS IS WHAT I WOULD LIKE TO DO NOW--------------------------------------

Once an account is validated and redirected to the Welcome.jsp I would like that page to show a button that says "Choose File", which when clicked will allow you to browse your computer for files. From there I should be able to select a .csv file that I can parse and enter into the database. Maybe the .csv will contain something as simple as:

```
Username , Password

UserTest1, 123
UserTest2, 234
UserTest3, 567
UserTest4, 890
```

So these are my questions regarding this whole procedure:

- Is it possible to use JS inside a JSP to accomplish my task?
- Is it a good idea to use JS inside a JSP to do it?
- If I were to built a more complex website is it recommended to build it using html,css and jQuery code inside the JSP?

The whole idea is to build a a website that allows the admin ONLY to enter a .csv file containing a list of prices for items, that will be grabbed by the website and uploaded into the database, which in return will show a new stock of items for a certain product. I know that I am far from done, but this is just a start. :)

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need JavaScript to upload a file
2. I don't see how it would help. Just use a input of type file
3. You can of course use JavaScript, whatever you use at server-side to generate the HTML pages. Embedding JavaScript code inside HTML pages is a bad practice though. You should try to externalize the JS code to .js files as much as possible.

Just a few notes regarding the title and body of your question:

- reading a CSV file is the job of the controller, not the job of the view
- using the session to pass objects from a servlet controller to a view is not what you should do. You should use the request to do that.

Comment: 1. What do you mean by an input of type "file"? 2. I am aware that using JS inside a HTML page is bad practice, but I didn't know if the same rules applied when using HTML inside a JSP.

Comment: `<input type="file" name="theFile"/>`

Comment: I was thinking and wouldn't it be better to have an HTML,CSS, and JS page all separated and then have my Log_In.jsp and Sign_Up.jsp just show a simple page that will only require the user to enter their credentials?

Comment: I am used to retrieving inputs from text boxes, so I would normally store in the Controller as a string.                                   Ex. String email = request.getParameter("txtEmail");                   How can I store an manipulate a whole .csv file?

Comment: Google for *upload file to Java servlet*.

Comment: Alright, I found a few interesting articles. Thank you.  On a different note, How can I format these comments properly? It says to add two spaces at the end of a line to make a break, but it doesn't work.   :S

Comment: I have this other question that I asked earlier today, could you help me with it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457620/adding-a-calendar-to-my-website/15461254?noredirect=1#15461254 @JB Nizet

Answer (score 0):

You can't read files with JS because it doesn't have permission to access the filesystem.

You will have to upload the file into the server and get the parsing done from there.

There are tons of examples for JSP file uploading in the net.

Most complex websites employ the technologies/libraries you have listed so the answer is yes use them and it will increase usability and look and feel.